# Quotient space $D(2)/D(1)$ homeomorphic to $D(1)$

Tags: general-topology

I want to show that the quotient space $D(2)/D(1)$ is homeomorphic to $D(1)$ where $D(r)$ is a closed disk of radius $r$. Is there a specific function from $D(2)/D(1)$ to construct a homeomorphism? I don't know what I'm missing here.

Comment: What do you mean by $D(2)$ and by $D(1)$?

Comment: Sorry I should have been more explicit. I mean the closed discs of radius 1 and 2 respectively.

Comment: Is $D(2)$ a topological group?

Comment: @Stefan, perhaps Steve means quotient *space*, rather than quotient *group*.

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to (start to) answer the question on the assumption that we are talking about a quotient space, rather than a quotient group.

Consider $D(2)$ centered at the origin of a plane with polar coordinates. Consider the map $f:D(2)\to D(1)$ given as follows: if $r\gt1$, then $f(r,\theta)=(r-1,\theta)$; otherwise, $f(r,\theta)$ is the origin. The map factors through the quotient space $D(2)/D(1)$ since it is constant on $D(1)$. Now you can try to show that, as a map from $D(2)/D(1)$ to $D(1)$, it's a homeomorphism.

Comment: Hi, what does "factors through the quotient space $D(2)/D(1)$" mean? Thank you.

Comment: @JKnecht, given a function $f:A\to B$, "$f$ factors through $C$" means there are functions $g:A\to C$ and $h:C\to B$ such that $f=h\circ g$.